# Prove a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

**Question:** Show using the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition that

Comment: On "My attempt". That's wrong. You have to prove that given $M>0,$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0<|z-i|<\delta$ implies $|(z-1)/(z^2+1)| > M.$

Comment: Sorry, yes that is what I meant, however is the method correct?

Comment: If not, could you explain why not? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let $B>0$ be given.  Let $w=z-i$ and restrict $w$ so that $|w|<1$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{z-1}{z^2+1}\right|&= \left|\frac{w-(1-i)}{w(w+2i)}\right|\\\\
&\ge \frac{\left|\,|w|-\sqrt 2\,\right|}{|w|\,(|w|+2)}\\\\
&\ge \frac{\sqrt 2 -1}{3|w|}\\\\
&>B
\end{align}$$

whenever $|z-i|<\min\left(1,\frac{\sqrt 2 -1}{3B}\right)$.  And we are done!